# How to have another "instance" of stages?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have the usual

```
stages:
 - build
 - test
 - deploy
```

works fine

now I need to do something completely unrelated -- downloading bunch of stuff every midnight
I setup the scheduled job, but it mandatorily needs a stage

But if I add a stage "download_stuff" it will obviously be the part of that pipeline, meaning some sequential step

I wan't none of this, downloads are completely unrelated, and should not be part of that sequence

Basically I want this

```
pipeline_a:
   stages:
    - build
    - test
    - deploy
    
pipeline_b:
   stages:
      - "download_stuff"
```

Any way to do this, other want forcibly adding it to the stages, and then `except`ing everywhere? Seems like a big design flaw, unless I'm stupidly missing something obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to define two separate pipelines. You can include stages and jobs from other pipeline definitions, but at runtime it is still considered one single pipeline. The only way to prevent some jobs from running when scheduled is to use `only` like you mentioned, or the newer syntax `rules`.

With `only`, you can make some jobs only run when scheduled:

```
download_job:
  stage: downloads
  only: schedules
  ..
```

Or vice-versa for a build/test/deploy job:

```
build_job
  stage: build
  except: schedules
```

The `rules` keyword is newer than `only`/`except` and lets you write more complicated conditionals when needed.

```
download_job:
  stage: downloads
  when: never
  rules:
    - if: "$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'schedules'"
      when: always
      allow_failure: true
      start_in: 3 hours
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == 'main'"
      when: manual
```

When there are multiple `if`'s, they're OR'ed together, but you can use `||` and `&&` inline to make a more complicated rule:

```
...
  rules:
    - if: "$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'schedule' && $GITLAB_USER_EMAIL == 'myemail@me.com'
      when: manual
  ..
```

Comment: I see, thats unfortunate, as you now need to remember to add the filtering on every new job